# Python regex remove all character except 4 digitals

Tags: python, regex

```
+1511
0716
+4915 CZECHY
+3815/0616 PORT MO,
AO
_3615 USA *, SUV run on flat
+4515 PORT SUV
*, SUV
+3215 USA *, SUV
+4414
+4815 NIEM
_0616 NIEM  * / MO
+2115 NIEM J
```

I need get only first 4 digits

> +**3715** NIEM

Please help.

Comment: I used `re.sub(r'(\+|\_)\d{3}[0-9]','', dot)` but its remove +/_XXXX not replace :(

Comment: This supplement belongs to the post, not a comment.

Comment: I used CTRL+F on this page with `3715`, and only found this value in your expected output. Please check your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't described your data very well, but it looks like you have two types of lines:

> (one or zero characters)(four digits)(other stuff)

or

> (other stuff with no set of four digits)

I propose using the `re` package. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html) is the documentation for the module in Python 3, which you should really read to be able to solve these problems on your own in the future.

I'll assume you have all your lines in a list (or other iterable) named `lines`:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'^.?([0-9]{4})')
for line in lines:
    match = regex.match(line)
    if match:
        number = match.group(0)
        # Do stuff with `number`, which is a string.
```

This assumes that there is only ever one character ahead of the four-digit number, and that you don't care about whatever comes afterward.

If you simply wanted *any* first four digits that appear (with any number of characters in advance), you could instead use `regex = re.compile(r'[0-9]{4}')`.

---

**How the Regex Works**

The first regex is `^.?([0-9]{4}`. I'll break this down for you, because I'm guessing you're new to regexes.

- `^` matches the beginning of the line
- `.` matches *any* character exactly once
- `?` says to make the previous match either 0 or 1 times

  - so `.?` says "give me at most one character that I don't know"
- `()` parentheses are used for *grouping*, which tells the regex engine "do the match, but let me access these things specifically on their own"
- `[]` are for specifying a *class* of characters; the engine will match one character from inside the brackets

  - `[0-9]` is the character class for digits: the `-` matches everything inclusive in ASCII ordering (I believe)
- `{N}` specifies to repeat the previous thing exactly `N` times

  - `[0-9]{4}` says "give me four digits"

When we put it all together as `^.?([0-9]{4})`, we're effectively saying to the regex engine: "Give me a string that starts at the beginning of the line and might have an extra character at the beginning, and then has four digits immediately afterwards. I really only care about the digits, though, so let me access those directly."